# converting long string values (ethereum wei) to number in mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of documents that have a property named "balance" storing ethereum wei.

sample data stored inside the balance fields look like this "256873382898626676750809"

What I need to do know is to group and some these values in an aggregation so I tried using the $toLong converter which throws an error: "value overflow". I am guessing the string is too long to convert, but what other options do I have using MongoDB?

Comment: Try `$toDecimal`

Comment: oh wow that actually worked, sometimes its so easy and hard when you have tomatoes on your eyes. Thank you :S